# File Fuzzing with Peach

Tags: fuzzing

I am a beginner in file fuzzing.I want to fuzz Adrenalin Player 2.2.5.3 with peach 3 and during compile got a problem. when I enter this command `c:\peach\peach.exe wav.xml` receive this error: `unable to locate test named "Default"`.

and here is my code in xml :

```
<!-- Defines the common wave chunk -->
<DataModel name="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" length="4" padCharacter=" " />
    <Number name="Size" size="32" >
        <Relation type="size" of="Data" />
    </Number>
    <Blob name="Data" />
    <Padding alignment="16" />
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkData" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="data" token="true"/>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkFact" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="fact" token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Number size="32" />
        <Blob/>
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkSint" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="sInt" token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Number size="32" />
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkWavl" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="wavl" token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Block name="ArrayOfChunks" maxOccurs="3000">
            <Block ref="ChunkSint"/>
            <Block ref="ChunkData" />
        </Block>
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkCue" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="cue " token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Block name="ArrayOfCues" maxOccurs="3000">
            <String length="4" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <String length="4" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
        </Block>
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkFmt" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="fmt " token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Number name="CompressionCode" size="16" />
        <Number name="NumberOfChannels" size="16" />
        <Number name="SampleRate" size="32" />
        <Number name="AverageBytesPerSecond" size="32" />
        <Number name="BlockAlign" size="16" />
        <Number name="SignificantBitsPerSample" size="16" />
        <Number name="ExtraFormatBytes" size="16" />
        <Blob name="ExtraData" />
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkPlst" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="plst" token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Number name="NumberOfSegments" size="32" >
            <Relation type="count" of="ArrayOfSegments"/>
        </Number>
        <Block name="ArrayOfSegments" maxOccurs="3000">
            <String length="4" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
        </Block>
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkLtxt" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="ltxt" token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="16" />
        <Number size="16" />
        <Number size="16" />
        <Number size="16" />
        <String nullTerminated="true" />
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkSmpl" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="smpl" token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Number size="32" />
        <Block maxOccurs="3000">
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
            <Number size="32" />
        </Block>
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<DataModel name="ChunkInst" ref="Chunk">
    <String name="ID" value="inst" token="true"/>
    <Block name="Data">
        <Number size="8"/>
        <Number size="8"/>
        <Number size="8"/>
        <Number size="8"/>
        <Number size="8"/>
        <Number size="8"/>
        <Number size="8"/>
    </Block>
</DataModel>

<!-- Defines the format of a WAV file -->
<DataModel name="Wav">
    <!-- wave header -->
    <String value="RIFF" token="true" />
    <Number size="32" />
    <String value="WAVE" token="true"/>

    <Choice maxOccurs="30000">
        <Block ref="ChunkFmt"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkData"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkFact"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkSint"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkWavl"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkCue"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkPlst"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkLtxt"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkSmpl"/>
        <Block ref="ChunkInst"/>
        <Block ref="Chunk"/>
    </Choice>
</DataModel>

<!-- This is our simple wave state model -->
<StateModel name="TheState" initialState="Initial">
    <State name="Initial">

        <!-- Write out our wave file -->
        <Action type="output">
            <DataModel ref="Wav"/>
            <!-- This is our sample file to read in -->
            <Data fileName="sample.wav"/>
        </Action>

        <Action type="close"/>

        <!-- Launch the target process -->
        <Action type="call" method="StartMPlayer" publisher="Peach.Agent" />
    </State>
</StateModel>

<Agent name="WinAgent">
   <Monitor class="WindowsDebugger">

        <!-- The command line to run.  Notice the filename provided matched up
             to what is provided below in the Publisher configuration -->
        <Param name="CommandLine" value="c:\\Program Files (x86)\\adrenalin\\play.exe fuzzed.wav" />

        <!-- This parameter will cause the debugger to wait for an action-call in
             the state model with a method="StartMPlayer" before running
             program.
        -->
        <Param name="StartOnCall" value="StartMPlayer" />

        <!-- This parameter will cause the monitor to terminate the process
             once the CPU usage reaches zero.
        -->
        <Param name="CpuKill" value="true"/>

    </Monitor>

    <!-- Enable heap debugging on our process as well. -->
    <Monitor class="PageHeap">
        <Param name="Executable" value="c:\\Program Files (x86)\\adrenalin\\play.exe"/>
    </Monitor>

</Agent>

<Agent name="LinAgent">
    <!-- Register for core file notifications. -->
    <Monitor class="LinuxCrashMonitor"/>

    <Monitor class="Process">
        <!-- The executable to run. -->
        <Param name="Executable" value="mplayer"/>

        <!-- This parameter will cause the monitor to wait for an action-call in
             the state model with a method="StartMPlayer" before running
             program.
        -->
        <Param name="StartOnCall" value="StartMPlayer"/>

        <!-- The program arguments.  Notice the filename provided matched up
             to what is provided below in the Publisher configuration -->
        <Param name="Arguments" value="fuzzed.wav"/>

        <!-- This parameter will cause the monitor to terminate the process
             once the CPU usage reaches zero.
        -->
        <Param name="CpuKill" value="true"/>
    </Monitor>

</Agent>

<Agent name="OsxAgent">
    <Monitor class="CrashWrangler">
        <!-- The executable to run. -->
        <Param name="Command" value="mplayer" />

        <!-- The program arguments.  Notice the filename provided matched up
             to what is provided below in the Publisher configuration -->
        <Param name="Arguments" value="fuzzed.wav" />

        <!-- Do not use debug malloc. -->
        <Param name="UseDebugMalloc" value="false" />

        <!-- Treat read access violations as exploitable. -->
        <Param name="ExploitableReads" value="true" />

        <!-- Path to Crash Wrangler Execution Handler program. -->
        <Param name="ExecHandler" value="/usr/local/bin/exc_handler" />

        <!-- This parameter will cause the monitor to wait for an action-call in
             the state model with a method="StartMPlayer" before running
             program.
        -->
        <Param name="StartOnCall" value="StartMPlayer" />

    </Monitor>
</Agent>
    <Test name="Default">
    <Agent ref="WinAgent" platform="windows"/>
    <Agent ref="LinAgent" platform="linux"/>
    <Agent ref="OsxAgent" platform="osx"/>

    <StateModel ref="TheState"/>

    <Publisher class="File">
        <Param name="FileName" value="fuzzed.wav"/>
    </Publisher>
    <Logger class="Filesystem">
        <Param name="Path" value="logs" />
    </Logger>
</Test>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your line `<Test name="Default">` should probably include an absolute path (or a relative path that works properly) instead of only a test name. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Peach Framework, your pit files(the xml file you have included) must be completed encapsulated by a `<Peach>.........</Peach>` tag. Try this and see what happens!